# How to target the Input element of all dynamic forms generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When you press the button 'Show Text' - I want the alert box to display **all text** that has been entered into **any** of the input boxes generated by this dynamically made form.

I've used the code below to target: the p class and input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert("Value: " + $("input",'.n').val());
    });
```

The above code only seems to return the text in whatever input box was used first..

..so if you click on ***note1*** then ***note2*** you only get 'Hello'(rather than: hello
                                                                        goodbye)

..if you click on **note2** then ***note1*** you only get 'Goodbye' (rather than: goodbye
                                                                         hello)

Please can anyone help!

```js
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

/*     Template 1    */
$('#addNew1').live('click', function(e) {
$('<p class="n"><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="hello" placeholder="This is note 1" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;
e.preventDefault();

});

/*     Template 2    */
$('#addNew2').live('click', function(e) {
$('<p class="n"><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="goodbye" placeholder="This is note 2" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);

i++;
e.preventDefault();
});

/*     Template 3    */
$('#addNew3').live('click', function(e) {
$('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="Say cheese!" placeholder="This is note 3" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;

e.preventDefault();
});

$('#remNew').live('click', function(e) {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
e.preventDefault();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert("Value: " + $("input",'.n').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Note Template</h2>

   <a href="#" id="addNew1">note1</a> 
   <a href="#" id="addNew2">note2</a>
   <a href="#" id="addNew3">note3</a>
   
 <div id="addinput">
  <p> </p>
 </div>
 
 <button id="btn1">Show Text</button> 
 <input class="n" type="text" value="some text">

</body>
</html>
```

Incase anyone wants to try it.. the new code function that works is below (just replace the first code snippet with this one)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
 var txt = $(".n input").map(
        function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }
     ).get().join("\n");
     console.log(txt);
  alert("This is my note" + txt);
```

Comment: FYI: live has been deprecated and removed from modern versions of jQuery. You really should upgrade to a newer version. 1.4 is 4 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val() only returns the value of the first input as it is stated in the documentation. If you want to show all the values, you would need to loop through all the inputs and build up the string.

```
var str = [];
$(".n input").each(
    function () {
        str.push($(this).val());
    }
);
console.log(str.join("\n"));
```

instead of each, you could use jQuery map

```
var txt = $(".n input").map(
        function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }
    ).get().join("\n");
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. Sorry for being dizzy (I'm really new to and learning JQuery)  Do I need to insert this code after the    $("btn1").click (function () {    to get it to work?

Comment: If you want it to run on click, you would add it inside the function in the click.